# What are the dimensions of the FlashForge Creator Pro heating block?

Tags: flashforge-creator, flashforge

I have a FlashForge Creator Pro, couple of years old.  I'm looking to replace one or both of the heating blocks, as they're getting old and pretty gunked up.  Instead of buying two blocks at \$30 each, I thought I could take some aluminum and make two on my CNC mill.  The only thing - are there any manufacturer provided dimensions?  I could probably get by measuring with calipers, but I'd prefer the exact specifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FlashForge Creator Pro uses a [MK10 hotend](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/a/5437/5740):

[image]

The Micro Swiss MK10 All Metal Hotend Kit for instance is reported to be a drop-in replacement for the FlashForge Creator Pro, it uses M7 threads.

The heater block for an MK10 has a threaded hole for the thermistor (M4), but some use a machined hole for PT100/3 mm thermistor cartridges. The block measures around 20 x 20 13 mm. The images below should give you enough information to create your custom blocks. However, there appear to be 3<sup>rd</sup> supplier after-market blocks available on on-line webshops and market places

[image]

[image]

[image]

The Flashforge original spare part heater blocks show that they are slightly different (the top image shows symmetrical heater blocks while the spare parts are not symmetrical), so above drawings and caliper measurements should give you enough information to reproduce the heater block.

[image]

---

*It would be a great addition if you added your own answer once you measured your blocks and created some drawings!*